# Can you see the time a document was indexed in ElasticSearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

Does ElasticSearch store any meta data that indicate when a document was actually indexed? If not is there any way to default a field to current date like how in MySQL you can default a column to NOW()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can enable [_timestamp](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-timestamp-field.html) , and get this functionality.

Comment: this page no longer exist